# How to close Spring MongoOperations connection?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
 MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
```

I specifically don't want to usr mongoTemplate to close the connection , is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but I found the answer here (unzoomed response) https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040751/5825651

> Solved by replacing MongoOperations with the implementation MongoTemplate and then on the MongoTemplate call mongoTemplate.getDb().getMongo().close();

Regards!

Comment: `mongoTemplate.getDb().getMongo()` does not exist anymore in the current MongoDb version (as of ~2022).